# XPath to locate a cell with specific text parsing HTML tables

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, groovy, htmlunit

Hope someone out there can quickly point me in the right direction with my XPath difficulties.

Current I've got to the point where I'm identifying the correct table i need in my HTML source but then I need to process only the rows that have the text 'Chapter' somewhere in the DOM.

My last attempt was to do this :

```
// get the correct table
HtmlTable table = page.getFirstByXPath("//table[2]");

// now the failing bit....
def rows = table.getByXPath("*/td[contains(text(),'Chapter')]")
```

I thought the xpath above would represent, get me all elements that have a following child element of 'td' that somewhere in its dom contains the text 'Chapter'

An example of a matching row from my source is :

```
<tr valign="top">
  <td nowrap="" align="Right">
   <font face="Verdana">
   <a href="index.cfm?a=1">Chapter 1</a>
   </font>
  </td>
  <td class="ChapterT">
    <font face="Verdana">DEFINITIONS</font>
  </td>
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

Any help / pointers greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use this XPath:

```
//td[contains(., 'Chapter')]
```

Comment: Thanks, that appears to work.  What does the '.' represent?    Also I don't understand why the 'reletive' detection isn't working, e.g. you have the // which as I understand means begin at the root?

Comment: @Dave, You're welcome. `.` and `//` is XPath abbreviated syntax. `.` selects the context node. `//td` selects all the `td` descendants of the document root and thus selects all `td` elements in the same document as the context node. *Reference*: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev

Answer (score 9):

**You want all `td`s under your current node -- not**  - *all in the document* **as the currently accepted answer selects**.

**Use**:

```
.//td[.//text()[contains(., 'Chapter')]]
```

This selects all `td` descendants of the current node that are named `td` that have at least one text node descendant, whose string value contains the string `"Chapter"`.

**If it is known in advance that any `td` under this `table` only has a single text node, this can be simplified to just**:

```
.//td[contains(., 'Chapter')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Your on the right "path".
The contains() function is limited the a specific element, not text in any of the children.  Try this XPath, which you could read as follows:
- get every tr/td with any sub element that contains the text 'Chapter'

```
tr/td[contains(*,"Chapter")]
```

Good luck

Comment: Hi William, gave it a go but couldn't get it to return anything.  What has worked, although doesn't seem the most efficient is a single liner of '    
def chapterAnchors = page.anchors.findAll {HtmlAnchor a -> a.asText().contains('Chapter')}   '